# Lookup Error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I get the above error when i run the below code.

```
UPDATE MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS SET "Created" = TO_DATE(11/18/2013 9:21:44 AM, MM/DD/YYYY  hh:mi:ss)
        where ID =365020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have:

```
UPDATE MANUAL_TRANSACTIONS
SET "Created" = TO_DATE('11/18/2013 9:21:44 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
WHERE ID = 365020
```

Without the single quotes it will surely give you an error. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm)

Comment: the above code is returning this error. Lookup Error
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string